# Set Docker CPU and RAM limits in Mac and Linux

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would like to set a RAM & CPU limits for a container that needs more resources than the default.
In mac, I have set the resources manually via the docker for Mac GUI, changing the general used CPU/RAM for docker.

Still, I'm not sure regarding:
1. In mac, How do I set it for a specific container only, meaning I want a single container to use X resources, while others use the default.
2. How do I share this configuration with my team (instead of guiding them to manually change via GUI)
3. How do I increase resources limits in Linux machine where there is no GUI?
4. Does cpu_count/mem_limit works on Mac as well as on Linux?

I'm using docker-compose to set up my services.

Answer (score 0):

> In mac, How do I set it for a specific container only, meaning I want a single 
>   container to use X resources, while others use the default

You can check the [docker run options in the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-resources). There are the `--cpu*` options to control cpu usage and the `--memory` to limit memory usage.

> How do I share this configuration with my team (instead of guiding
>   them to manually change via GUI)

Similar options can be specified in a [docker compose file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#resources). Create a docker-compose file and share it with your team via git ...

Comment: 1. I'm using compose not docker run 2. I mean sharing MAC configuration (the one I change via the GUI)

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still looking for a solution (on MAC);

```
# docker-machine inspect
```

this will print current memory with other information and also the location where config file is placed `StorePath`;

```
{
"ConfigVersion": 3,
"Driver": {
    "IPAddress": "192.168.64.2",
    "MachineName": "default",
    ...
    "StorePath": "/Users/lw5523/.docker/machine",
    ....
    "CPU": 1,
    "Memory": 1024,
    "DiskSize": 20000,
    ...
    "Vmlinuz": "vmlinuz64"
},
```

Note this `StorePath` and modify CPU and Memory information. After modification you need to restart the docker-machine i.e. if its default;

```
# docker restart
```

and check new memory;

```
# docker-machine ssh default free
```

will give you current memory and how much is free.